# Missing class: com.google.android.aidl.BaseProxy

Tags: android, aidl

Occasionally after generating the Signed APK, the following warning would appear

```
Missing class: com.google.android.aidl.BaseProxy
Missing Class: com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub
```

However, the APK would be successfully generated. Only when released the warning would be detrimental to the app.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub
```

What gradle dependancy is required so this class is found and resolved?

Here are links to my gradle files (shared on google drive):

[build.gradle (module: app)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CennE8rL_fe3LBAQYx6nUCiCu_QlBnNe/view?usp=sharing)

[build.gradle (project)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QNzAgNo9L3BCxx60e4sgKg1LY5iectT-/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

Comment: please update your question with your build.gradle files. There's something wrong in the dependencies/buildToolsVersion.

Comment: thank you for checking, updated question with links to files (hope that is ok)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your *proguard rules* with the following:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.aidl.** { *; }
```

> **EDIT:** ([from proguard documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage))

**-keep:** Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as entry points to your code.

**-keepclassmembers:** Specifies class members (only) to be preserved, if their classes are preserved as well.

If you specify a class, without class members, ProGuard only preserves the class and its parameterless constructor as entry points. It may still remove, optimize, or obfuscate its other class members.

If you specify a method, ProGuard only preserves the method as an entry point. Its code may still be optimized and adapted.

So if you're not sure which option you need, you should probably simply use **-keep**. It will make sure the specified classes and class members are not removed in the shrinking step, and not renamed in the obfuscation step.

(below *-keep* includes all classes and class members from *aidl*)

```
-keep class com.google.android.aidl.** { *; }
```

In your case you are missing *BaseProxy* and *BaseStub* classes. You can specify only these classes in your *-keep* and *-keepclassmembers* and test which method is suitable for you with best code obfuscation for your release build.

(below *-keep* includes only *BaseProxy* and *BaseStub*)

```
-keep class com.google.android.aidl.BaseProxy { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub { *; }
```

My suggestion is to specify the class names you don't want to remove and utilize the code obfuscation to reduce your app size.

Comment: Thanks, the proguard update seems to supress the warning. Could just "-keep" be used instead of "-keepclassmembers"?

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms of your issue (only happens in release build means proguard is removing the class) leads me to suggest :

1. if the class missing is one of yours add this annotation to the that class

> `@Keep class TheClass { ... }`

2. if the class giving you pain is in the third party lib (mostly you add lib  via gradle file in your project ) then normally in the library readme file (from their website like Github repo readme etc ) there is a proguard rules note that you need to add something like :

> ```
> # Parceler library
> -keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
> -keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
> -keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }
> ```